# Racket - Find the largest prime in a range

Tags: racket

I'm writing a function largest-prime which consumes two natural numbers and produces the largest prime number in the range from bottom to top. 
I used a helper-function is-prime? to check if the number is prime or not.

Below is my code:

```
(define (largest-prime bottom top)
  (cond
    [(and (>= top bottom)(equal? true (is-prime? top))) top]
    [(and (< top bottom) (equal? true (is-prime? top))) false]
    [else (largest-prime (sub1 top) bottom)]))
```

It seems that this function only works with certain cases:

```
> (largest-prime 12 19)
19
> (largest-prime 12 18)
17
> (largest-prime 12 16)
false
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have switched `bottom` and `top` in your *else* case, so you can fix that to:

```
[else (largest-prime bottom (sub1 top))]
```

Another thing to note, you don't need to equate the return value of `is-prime?` to "true" or "false". It is sufficient to simply use the return value as the conditional. For example, consider the following:

```
(define (largest-prime bottom top)
  (cond
    [(< top bottom) false]
    [(is-prime? top) top]
    [else
     (largest-prime bottom (sub1 top))]))
```